# UML - Relation between Java classes when not defined in a field

Tags: java, uml

```
class ClassA {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // has-a, composition 

    public ClassA() 
    {
       frame.add(new ClassB());
    }       
}
```

is there a name for the relationship/association between ClassA and Classb? ClassA does not have a field for ClassB.

I have read about class associations in "Introduction to Java Programming" by Y. Daniel Liang and used google, but can't find an example with this specific relation.

i'm drawing an UML diagram of some existing code and want to get the correct relation annotation.

Maybe i'm overthinking it and it's just simply an association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instances of *ClassB* are memorized through a *JFrame* so you can use a class-relation :

[image]

or just add a dependency from *ClassA* to *ClassB*

Comment: ok - Is it correct to say that the relation frame->ClassB is aggregated? I can't edit the code btw.

Comment: @Kapalua if my proposal is not correct someone else will warm me ^^  I made my proposal from your code, so your code is compatible with and you do not have to change it

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the input, but i don't quite get why you have placed a composition relation between ClassA and ClassB. wouldn't that mean that ClassA have a field like this: ClassB classB?

Comment: @Kapalua I used a composition because of your comment `// has-a, composition`. "ClassA have a field like this: ClassB classB" : no, _frame_ is enough because this is not a relation but a class-relation, _JFrame_ has the link to (a mother class of) _ClassB_

Comment: Ok - i was not aware of that way of modelling. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Done. As a sidenote, right now it seems to me like modelling these diagrams are not a straightforward process. It seems that the details in the diagram will be heavily influenced by the perspective of the person making it.

Comment: @Kapalua this is very true, this is because UML allows to model more than just the fact a class has some attributes and operations or inheritance etc even just through a class diagram, and they are different kind of diagrams in UML, and all details in the model cannot be shown too in  diagrams. A diagram has a goal, you do not decide randomly what are the shown elements nor how you show them inside.

Answer (score 1):

A private attribute is usually modeled as a unidirectional Association (even though navigability could also be achieved by other means than an owned attribute).

Your source code defines attribute `frame`, therefore, you should model an Association between `ClassA` and `JFrame`.

Then class `JFrame` has an `add` operation for a `ClassB` object. This makes only sense, if `JFrame` has an Association to `ClassB`.

Finally `ClassA` creates a new instance of `ClassB`. This fact can be visualized by a «create» Relationship (a dashed open arrow).

No other relationship between `ClassA` and `ClassB` exists. Since we don’t know, whether `JFrame`s attribute is private, it might even be impossible for `ClassA` to access `ClassB`, even though it created it.

A Composition could exist between `JFrame` and `ClassB`, but your Source Code doesn’t give enough context for this decision. It makes no sense between ClassA and ClassB, since they don’t even are associated, be it by an AssociationClass and by a normal Association.

Comment: My ideas seem to align along the same lines as what you are writing. Thanks for making it more clear.